# Network requirements for OTA deploy

Tags: ios, ssl, ota

I have found following network requirements for OTA deployment:
https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7

> Network configuration requirements
>
> If the devices are connected to a closed internal network, you should let iOS devices access the following:
>
> ax.init.itunes.apple.com:  The device obtains the current file-size limit for downloading apps over the cellular network. If this website isn’t reachable, installation may fail.
>
> ocsp.apple.com:  The device contacts this website to check the status of the distribution certificate used to sign the provisioning profile.

I want to ask is it possible to deploy through intranet without access above website? Any work around?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have OTA setup in our intranet. Works fine. Only requirement is that the device installing the app should be connected to the VPN or in the intranet.